# Two <h1> tags on all pages showing same content

Tags: seo, html, tags

Hi I have a little problem. The website theme we are using displays the website name at the top of every page as an  element the title of the post then gets displayed as an  element again. Effectively having two  tags on the page. Here is an image with example:

[image]

The circled content in the top left corner of the image gets displayed on every page, than my actual h1 tag gets displayed in the body section as can also be seen on the image

**My Question**

- Is the above a problem?
- Will it affect my sites overall SEO performance even though we are
  producing quality content?
- **The bottom line is this: Should I get a developer to fix it or is it okay/safe leaving it as is?**

Comment: @Simon Hayter Can you please give me a link to the post where it has been asked already...Thanks Simon

Comment: It is right at the top:  [SEO regarding using multiple <h1> tag?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/seo-regarding-using-multiple-h1-tag)