# Are multiple H1 tags on a carousel better for SEO?

Tags: seo, content, heading

Does having a hero-slider with more content above the fold have an effect on SEO compared to a static hero with less content?

I am aware that sliders have terrible click-through rates past the first slider and what not, but I'm curious if having, for example, a hero-slider with 1 slide dictating the main service, then 2 sub-service slides has a positive effect on SEO, compared to just having 1 static hero dictating the main service, then having the sub services below the fold.

I'd personally like to have a static hero, however if a slider is better for SEO, then that seems like a better option.

Comment: If the slider is unique and not repeated on every-page then your slider is not above the fold. It's a common mistake for people to assume that everything above a 'menu bar' or similar is always consider 'above the fold'. Google and Bing is far more complex than just looking at a menu bar and saying, that's above the fold... etc.

Comment: What is a hero-slider?  Are we talking about batman on 3rd base?

Comment: Hero slider is a one or more image slider that is responsive, full width and will often use effects like Ken Burns, 3D parallax and so on... lol at Batman.

Comment: I never fully understood it... its basically a slider... with a sales pitch... just like when everyone started adding 360 to their company name and products.

Comment: Also, for multiple h1 see: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/15895/seo-regarding-using-multiple-h1-tag as well as [dozens more like it](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+h1). Ideally, one always works best. If your using multiple H1 for styling purposes then you should correct the CSS and make H2 appear the same as H1.

Comment: Thanks for your replies Simon - Would you be able to elaborate on your first comment? The slider is unique to the home-page and is always visible on landing on all screen-sizes. My understanding is that that would be considered above-the-fold, at least by users. How does google determine above the fold?

Comment: The title asks about `h1`, while the question is about a slider -- does this imply that you want to use a `h1` for each slide?

Comment: Imagine you get a Book with several headings on the Cover. More than one H1 is a Mixed signal. In Best case they will be ignored, in the worSt they will reduce relevance

Answer (score 1):

UI elements that don't display content initially on their own URL are bad for SEO.  Google usually only indexed content that the user can see when landing on the page.   Content that it not visible to the user initially and requires a click, or waiting until it rotates into place will generally be ignored by Google.

If you want users to find your sub-services in Google search, it would be best to created full pages about each sub-service.   That way Google can index the content on those pages and send users who have searched directly to the appropriate content.